# browser prepends the domain to links

Tags: html

I'm trying to link to an element on the same page like this

```
<a href="#myelement">Link</a>

...

<div id="myelement">...</div>
```

But the browser keeps prepending the full domain to the link and it ends up linking to

```
http://example.com/#myelement
```

causing it to reload the page instead of moving to an element on the page. How do I get it to just link to #myelement?

Comment: Should work fine. Can you show us a test page that demonstrates this?

Comment: Right now its only on my dev machine. Which reminds me that I'm actually using a custom ".dev" domain on my development machine. So the link ends up looking like this: http://example.dev/#myelement. Could the fake ".dev" domain be the problem?

Comment: I put up a quick test page that demonstrates the problem. [link](http://hecotravel.com/request). the nav links on the side should link to different sections of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `<base href="http://hecotravel.com/">` element, which dictates that all links are relative to `http://hecotravel.com/`. Therefore a link to `#traveler` is a link to `http://hecotravel.com/#traveler`, which is a different page than `http://hecotravel.com/request`.

Either remove the `<base>` element or link to `request#traveler`.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot that I had that <base/> tag in there.